# What are the key differences/drawbacks to be aware of if I am running a cox regression vs a logistic regression controlling for survival time?

Tags: logistic, cox-model

A few times people have auggested to me to run a log reg with survival time as a covariate in place of a cox proportional hazards analysis. I am sure this has drawbacks but I am not sure what they might be. Anyone have an idea? When would you use one instead of the other?

Answer (score 1):

A simple model as you describe might not handle censored survival times (e.g., cases lost to follow up before an event), unless you take care in formatting the data set and setting up the regression model. That's certainly possible, as a discrete-time survival model is just a binomial regression on a properly designed data set. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/48613/28500) among many others on this site for an introduction to discrete-time survival. Discrete-time survival modeling via binomial regression becomes unwieldy, however, when there is a large number of survival times that differ among individuals. Then continuous-time models like Cox models or fully parametric models can make more sense.

Furthermore, if you do perform binomial regression for discrete-time survival, you might not want to use the default logit link. For example, the complementary log-log link most naturally matches the assumptions of proportional hazards. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/429266/28500).